# PHP Date Interval issue

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

Hi I am trying to add 90 seconds to a date stored in my DB and compare it with my current time and then take some decision. I have written following code. Also sharing response i am getting.

```
$curr_date_time=new DateTime('now');
$start_date_time=new DateTime($judge_obj->created_at);
$finish_date_time=$start_date_time->add(new DateInterval('PT90S'));

print_r($curr_date_time);
print_r($start_date_time); 
print_r($finish_date_time);
```

Response:

```
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2014-08-11 11:40:53 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC )
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2014-07-25 09:43:10 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC )
DateTime Object ( [date] => 2014-07-25 09:43:10 [timezone_type] => 3 [timezone] => UTC )
```

you see there is no difference in start_date_time and finish_date_time. please help

Answer (score 1):

The `add()` method modifies the DateTime object itself ("by reference" if you will), so calling

```
$start_date_time->add(new DateInterval('PT90S'));
```

will actually update `$start_date_time`

Use

```
$start_date_time = new DateTime($judge_obj->created_at);
$finish_date_time = clone $start_date_time;
$finish_date_time->add(new DateInterval('PT90S'));
```

Comment: Yes I read the manual where it states it updates the object but shouldn't it assign the updated value to $finish_date_time variable?

Comment: It does assign the result to `$finish_date_time` ___after___ it has updated `$start_date_time`..... `Returns the DateTime object for method chaining or FALSE on failure.`

Comment: Yes. Thanks i understand. And just to let you know there was no error. Printing times after variables being updated. would delete this post in a while. Thanks for your time and sorry from my side.